# Should notes on music sheet be numbered? Grade 1 piano

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I have a teacher who told me to keep them and another who said id learn better without them...

I feel the latter is better because im finding it extremely easy to play with numbers and music isnt supposed to be easy when growing; just like any skill im learning it cant be easy to progress and get into a higher level.

Attached is an example photo NOTE: ALL RIGHTS TO RESPECTFUL OWNERS I DO NOT MEAN TO SHARE THE NOTES OF THE SONG. IT IS MERELY TO HELP ANSWER MY QUESTION. FEEL FREE TO REMOVE IT AND SEND ME AN EMAIL IF NEEDED OR EVEN CLOSE IT.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ArhU.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

In simple music that sticks to a '5 finger' hand position, some beginners will try to avoid reading the notes by reading the fingerings instead!   It doesn't worry me too much.  Perhaps it delays proper reading by a tiny amount, but it CAN'T persist once extended hand positions and changes of position become necessary.  And a beginner can also be most ingenious in finding convoluted ways to mis-finger a simple passage!   Don't worry about it.  As you progress, you will encounter music with only occasional fingering instructions (which you would generally be well-advised to obey).  Until then, whatever enables fluent, well-fingered playing is good.